# Why is Array actually sorted but looking different on HTML?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to sort an array obtained by an **Observable**.
I have to make a http call `(this.myService.getReview(id))` using a property of res(the id) and add this property to `res['like_count']`. Finally I have to push res into `this.finalist` array, so I can use it in HTML code.

I need to sort it based on `like_count` value, to show items in the right order. As you can see below, I tried to implement a sort method but I'm not sure it's in the right position.

The result is that the first part of the items is in the correct order, but **at a certain point the order is random again**, while if I try to `console.log(this.finalist)` the order is right.

What could I try to solve it? Is it due to asynchronous functions?
Thanks

**component.ts**:

```
finalist = [];

.subscribe((res => {
            for (let i=0; i < res.length; i++) {
              for (let m=1; m < Object.keys(res[i]).length - 1; m++) {
                this.myService.getReview(res[i][m]['id'])
                .then((res2 => {
                    res[i][m]['like_count'] = parseInt(res2['like_count'])
                  if (!(this.finalist.some(e => e.title == this.reviewslist[i][m]['title']))) {
                    this.finalist.push(res[i][m])
                    this.finalist.sort(function(a,b) {return (a['like_count'] > b['like_count']) ? 1 : ((b['like_count'] > a['like_count']) ? -1 : 0);} );            
                  }
               }));
             }
           }
        console.log(this.finalist)
        // shows items in the right order
      }));
```

**component.html:**

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row *ngFor="let item of finalist | keyvalue">
        <ion-col>
          <img [src]="item?.value.image">
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="3">
          <p>{{item?.value.title | titlecase}}</p>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="9">
          <p>| N. of votes: {{item?.value.like_count}}</p>
        </ion-col>
     </ion-row>
   </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

**screens (from left to right):**

[image: screen1]
[image: screen2]

Comment: Are you sure `like_count` are numbers and not strings?

Comment: I used parseInt to convert them...is it wrong?

Comment: can you share your raw data that you receive from the http call?

Comment: put the `if (!(this.finalist.some(e => e.title == this.reviewslist[i][m]['title']))) {...` Into the `then((res=>{     res[i][m]['like_count'] = parseInt(res2['like_count'])***HERE***})`

Comment: @Eliseo I added a braket, my mistake, but still not working even inside .then()...

Comment: Maybe you should use a boolean variable like `isFinished` or something like that to make sure that your data is available and sorting is finished and only show the html with an `ngIf` directive when isFinished is true.

Comment: @standby954 since I have a lot of data to load, I'd like to show the user at least something before everything is completely loaded...is there a way to use a Boolean variable on the single item instead of the array? I mean, something like `*ngIf=isFinished` but where `isFinished` refers to array[0], then to array[1] and so on..

Comment: whether you tried sort by in the ngfor statment itself? *ngFor="let item of finalist | orderBy : {expression}

Comment: @Nagappan what if I use another pipe like keyvalue? I need to sort it by 'like_count' but 
`*ngFor="let item of finalist | orderBy: 'like_count' | keyvalue"` is not working...